# Access part of data from txt file in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have data.txt file

First line of this file is as follows

ATOM    00000000  -0.548  15.9994

where the 2nd field is "Frame Number" (i.e,00000000)
The subsequent lines of the data.txt file contain data of atoms of frame 1,2,...100 (i.e., 00000001, 00000002 ...).

There are about ~20k atoms in each frame. I need to load data from data.txt 
FRAME BY FRAME"(one frame at a time)

I know,

```
   val rawRDD = sc.textFile("data.txt")
```

gives me the whole file. But,I need to access frame by frame.
Can anyone help me do it

Comment: Are frames a fixed length?

Comment: yes all frames are of same length

Comment: CAn you give a more complete example? How do you know how many atoms  are in a frame? Is this  a delimited text file or binary file with fixed length fields?

Comment: you can do val `rawRDD = sc.textFile("data.txt").map(func)`

In that way you can do any function on each line,row.
As I understood your data is line separated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know in what version of Spark are you, but if possible, I would suggest you to try to use DataFrames instead.
In the meantime, hopefully I got your problem right, here is a possible solution with RDD's:

```
case class AtomData(category: String, frame: Int, x: Float, y: Float)
val rawRDD = sc.textFile("data.txt").map(line => {
    val fields = line.split("\\s")

    AtomData(fields(0), fields(1).toInt, fields(2).toFloat, fields(3).toFloat)
})

/**
 * If you already know the frames...
 */
val lastFrame = 100
for (i <- 0 to lastFrame) {
    val tmpRDD = rawRDD.filter(_.frame == i)
    // Do some stuff here...
}

/**
  * If you don't know the number of frames...
  */

val distinctFrames = rawRDD.map(_.frame).distinct.collect()
for (frame <- distinctFrames) {
    val tmpRDD = rawRDD.filter(_.frame == frame)
    // Do some stuff here
}
```